# How to override IsCorrectQtyCondition.php?

Tags: magento2, overrides, magento2.4.6

**Magento 2.4.6**

I had to make some changes to `vendor\magento\module-inventory-sales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsCorrectQtyCondition.php` and need to override that class now of course. How would I do that? I tried in my own module, but nothing I tried worked ... any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to override full class or function to custom module?

Comment: I had to make changes to the `execute` function ... so it would suffice to just override that function.

Comment: ok, please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step:-1** Create di.xml MyCompany/ModuleName/etc/di.xml and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsCorrectQtyCondition"
            type="MyCompany\ModuleName\Model\IsCorrectQtyCondition"/>
</config>
```

**Step:-2** Craete file IsCorrectQtyCondition.php MyCompany/ModuleName/Model/IsCorrectQtyCondition.php and add below code

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\ProductSalableResultInterface;

class IsCorrectQtyCondition extends \Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsCorrectQtyCondition
{

    public function execute(string $sku, int $stockId, float $requestedQty): ProductSalableResultInterface
    {
        // add logic here
    }

}
```

**Step:-3** Run the below commands and check.
**php bin/magento setup:di:compile**
**php bin/magento cache:flush**

Comment: Thanks, Ill try soon and let you know!

Comment: ok, Check and let me know